# Access to /usr/bin from web application - CentOS 5 64-bit dedicated hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, permissions

I'm trying to access `zip`, `unzip` and `du` from a web application.  I've done this before on other servers and had no problems, however when I enter the paths in `/usr/bin` the application reports that they're not correct.

I've checked and the paths are correct and I can use `zip` and `unzip` as root from SSH.  Is it a permissions thing?  Here are the ls -l outputs for each

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      66240  Feb  28 du
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      77280  Mar  11 zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     125432  Mar  11 unzip
```

Apache runs as `apache:apache` and I'm using PHP as a CGI application according to Plesk.  SELinux is currently `Disabled`

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `php.ini` and see if the function that you are using to run the programs have been disabled by the `disable_functions` setting e.g.

```
disable_functions=exec,shell_exec,system,proc_open ...
```

If the function you are using is listed, remove it.

EDIT: from the comments the solution was to set

```
safe_mode=off
```

in php.ini.

Comment: there are no disabled functions, thanks for helping

Comment: @sgtbeano: Can you tell us what function you are using and what the error message is please.

Comment: zip, unzip, du and aspell as detailed here  
docs.moodle.org/20/en/System_paths#Path_to_zip.  No error message I'm afraid other than a red X in the Moodle Admin interface next to each entry.

Comment: Found it, safe mode was on, switching this off fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help, I wouldn't have found it without you prompting me to look in the PHP ini.

Answer (score 2):

SELinux is probably enabled. Check that with `getenforce`. If it says `Enforcing`, SELinux is most likely the blocker. You may disable SELinux temporarily (until next reboot) with command `setenforce 0`, or permanently by modifying */etc/selinux/config* and setting SELinux disabled.

Alternatively you can modify SELinux settings to be more permissive with various SELinux tools available.

**EDIT:** So it seems SELinux is already disabled. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: It says `Disabled`

Comment: Added SELinux info to the original, thanks helping though

Comment: Please then paste the exact error message you're getting :)

Comment: That's the thing, there aren't any errors in the webapp (moodle), just a red X next to each path.  Here's the howto doc which I've read despite doing this countless times before.

Comment: http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/System_paths#Path_to_zip

Answer (score 0):

By editing php.ini, you are disabling safe_mode server wide. Actually, you have the option in your plesk itself under Plesk >> Domains >> Domain Name >> WebHosting Settings section to disable safe mode for particular domain. This will keep the master value to "On" and Local value to "Off" for the particular domain.